# Create a batch file where it will open eg: 50 processes of program X- and if total of program X doesn't match 50 (eg it crashed) to have it reopen

Tags: batch-file

So I'm currently trying to make a batch file where if program X will open 50 times - and if the amount of program X does not match 50 - eg it crashed etc, then it will reopen till it is once again 50.

Currently I have

```
:test
start /high /WAIT /D c:\test\ c:\test\Server.exe -file "c:\test\config\test.txt"
echo (%time%) WARNING: x closed or crashed
echo (%time%) Moving logs
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do set dateX=%%d-%%b-%%c
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:." %%a in ('echo %time%') do set timeX=%%a-%%b-%%c
mkdir "C:\test2 - test2\%dateX% %timeX%\"
move "%APPDATA%\test\log.txt" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2\test2\%dateX% %timeX%\log.txt"
echo (%time%) Logs moved. Restarting server...
ping localhost -n 10 > nul
goto :test
```

which basically has the reopen if crashed part + move text file over - but I just need the open/check 50 times part.

Any help will be appreciated -

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - to adapt to comments. Added delay between started instances of program

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem what to open
set "_process=notepad.exe"
set "_keep=4"

rem infinite loop: from 0 to 1 in steps of 0
for /l %%a in (0 0 1) do (
    rem get count of started processes
    for /f %%b in ('tasklist ^| find /c /i "%_process%"') do if %%b LSS %_keep% (
        rem start as many processes as needed
        set /a _started=%%b+1
        for /l %%c in (!_started! 1 %_keep%) do (
             start "" "%_process%"
             set /a _wait=(%%c-1)*2
             timeout /t %_wait% > nul
        )
    )
    rem wait
    timeout /t 3 > nul
)
```

Comment: Thanks! - that is somewhat perfect -however is there a way to make a delay when opening the program between each one - eg: lets say 2 out of the 4 opened, it will open one to make it 3, then lets say wait 10 seconds before it opens number 4 etc etc.

Comment: @user3020814: Changed answer to show how it can be done. Just an example. Adapt as needed.